# getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I run script from an OracleLinux 8.4 VM (with NatNetwork configured on VirtualBox) on my Windows 10 pc, to remote hosts using jump host.

My PC can't connect directly to remote hosts, but need to pass by jump host after connect to VPN.

This is my env:

| Server | IP |
| --- | --- |
| Windows PC LAN: | 192.168.0.10 |
| Windows PC VPN: | 10.201.66.134 |
| OracleLinux VM: | 10.0.100.100 |
| Jump Host | 90.x.x.x |

I use these parameters in my scirpt:

```
-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh -vvv -W %h:%p ispjh" 
-o PubkeyAuthentication=no 
-o PreferredAuthentications=password 
-o PasswordAuthentication=yes 
-o ControlMaster=auto 
-o ControlPersist=60s 
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

this is my ssh conf on VM:
[root@VM ~]# cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
TCPKeepAlive no
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 1296000

```
Host jumphost jumphost.mydonain.local
Hostname jumphost.mydonain.local
User user.name
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh-%r@%h:%p
DynamicForward 1083
```

I create a SSH tunneling before (with the command: `ssh jumphost -v`) and after I run the scripts, but when I run the script (on a new shell), after some time I receive this errors:
from SSH tunnelling connection:

```
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: channel 5: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for 10.12.12.14 port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536, nchannels 9
```

and sometime the script return and the connection dropped.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks for the support.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on a coworker computer with unclear conditions, just running this command:

ssh -J tunnel@host.example ssh://root@localhost:22

So I would say, try executing again that command, reducing the "unuseful" options, until the problem is still there. So, it's more simple to other people to help, with less entropy.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue and your comment help me resolve the issue by removing options `-o ConnectTimeout=3 -o ConnectionAttempts=1`. Thank you so much. @ValerioBozzolan